# Simply way to pass variables between processes?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

There's something I've been looking for a long time to solve, and can't find.

How can I pass variables between python processes, without using `Queue` or `Pipe`?

```
import multiprocessing

string = "hi"

def my_process():
  global string
  string = "success!" # but its only localy...


multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process).start()
```

I am looking for a way to change a variable from different scripts or processes...

Comment: what are you think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,

I created a package for Python to solve this problem.

---

## Install Guli from PIP.

```sh
$ pip install guli
```

Guli doesn't require installing any additional PIP package.

## With the package you can

Guli can be used to pass between different Python scripts, between many processes or at the same script.
pass variables between main Process and another (Multiprocess) Process.

- Pass variables between different Python scripts.
- Pass variables between 'Main Process' and another (Multiprocess) Process.
- Use variables at the same script.
- Create / Delete / Edit  -  GuliVariables.

#### Example

```py
import guli
import multiprocessing

string = guli.GuliVariable("hello").get()
print(string) # returns empty string ""

def my_function():
  ''' change the value from another process '''
  guli.GuliVariable("hello").setValue(4)

multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function).start()

import time
time.sleep(0.01) # delay after process to catch the update


string = guli.GuliVariable("hello").get()
print(string) # returns "success!!!"
```

Hope I solved the problem for many people!

Answer (score 0):

Guli don't work even on it's own example

```
runfile('Z:/Trading/dm_python_bot_mt/discord_bot_main.py', wdir='Z:/Trading/dm_python_bot_mt')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
prepare(preparation_data)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "Z:\Trading\dm_python_bot_mt\discord_bot_main.py", line 11, in 
multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function).start()
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 45, in **init**
prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
_check_not_importing_main()
File "H:\anaconda3\envs\plaid-ml\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```